# Is there a way to back a new Rails 5 attribute with two database columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking at using the new [Rails 5 attributes API](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html) for a custom data type, ideally storing the data in two database columns, one for the data `value` and one for some extra `type` information.

The Attributes API seems to be designed to work with just one database column and I'm wondering if I'm missing a way to use two columns.

#### Example

Imagine a Money object, with one `decimal` or `integer` column for value and one `string` column for currency code.  I'd pass in my custom money object, store it two columns, and then reading it back would combine the two columns into a Money object.

I've considered serializing the value and currency into a single Postgres JSON column, but I want to be able to do fast SQL `SUM` queries and sorting on just the value columns, so this doesn't seem ideal.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're thinking about creating a [ValueObject](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html) within your model.

There is [ActiveRecord::Aggregations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Aggregations/ClassMethods.html) for that. Example:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  composed_of :balance, class_name: "Money", mapping: %w(balance amount)
end

class Money
  include Comparable
  attr_reader :amount, :currency
  EXCHANGE_RATES = { "USD_TO_DKK" => 6 }

  def initialize(amount, currency = "USD")
    @amount, @currency = amount, currency
  end

  def exchange_to(other_currency)
    exchanged_amount = (amount * EXCHANGE_RATES["#{currency}_TO_#{other_currency}"]).floor
    Money.new(exchanged_amount, other_currency)
  end

  def ==(other_money)
    amount == other_money.amount && currency == other_money.currency
  end

  def <=>(other_money)
    if currency == other_money.currency
      amount <=> other_money.amount
    else
      amount <=> other_money.exchange_to(currency).amount
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Woah, yep. Aggregations looks great.  I'll poke around with these and report back here.  Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks for this.  It doesn't exactly fit my use case (I need to do a lot of type coercion on writes, using data already in the model) so I ended up continuing with my own getters and setters.  But it was definitely a good answer and I learned a new trick for next time.

Answer (score 1):

Can't answer your question directly unfortunately,  but your example got me thinking.  the money-rails gem allows use of a separate currency column.  Perhaps it would be worth it to dig thru that gem to see what they are doing behind the scenes.

Comment: Yep, we're thinking the same.  I've actually copied their existing implementation for my current code, which basically just overrides getters and setters.  With Rails 5 having an official attributes API now I thought I'd give that a shot.  I searched through the `money-rails` gem GH issues but couldn't find any talk about the new attributes API.